# No me pide permisos de ubicacion al usar Geocoder Ionic Cordova

Tags: typescript, ionic, cordova

mira resulta que tengo hecho un modal en el cual, entra y aparece un mapa, donde encuentra mi ubicación y luego escribe esa coordenada en latitud y longitud. Entonces ¿Cúal es el problema?
Estoy usando Ionic Cordova, y cuando hago `ionic cordova run browser --livereload` me funciona perfectamente, me pide los permisos de ubicación y tal, pero cuando buildeo la app, y la ejecuto, cuando llego a ese punto, ni me pide permisos ni nada. He probado activar los permisos manualmente desde ajustes, pero no hay. Es decir en el navegador hay y me los pide, pero en el movil nada, no existen. Os dejo el código por aqui

**page**

````
  @Input('nota') nota:Nota;
  coor:any;
  map: Map;
  newMarker: any;
  address: string[];
constructor(private geocoder: NativeGeocoder, private router: Router, 
  private modalController:ModalController,
 ) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.nota);
    
    
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.map.remove();
  }

ionViewDidEnter() {
  console.log("entro");
  
    this.loadMap();
  }
loadMap() {
    this.map = new Map("mapId").setView([17.385, 78.4867], 13);
tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
      attribution:
        'Francisco de los Rios'
    }).addTo(this.map);
  }
 locatePosition() {
    //let coor = await this.geo.getCurrentPosition(succes);
    this.map.locate({ setView: true }).on("locationfound", (e: any) => {
      this.newMarker = marker([e.latitude, e.longitude], {
        
        draggable: true
      }).addTo(this.map);
      this.newMarker.bindPopup("¡Te encuentras aquí!").openPopup();
      this.getAddress(e.latitude, e.longitude); // This line is added
      this.coor=e.latitude+" "+e.longitude;
      console.log(this.coor);
      
      this.newMarker.on("dragend", () => {
        const position = this.newMarker.getLatLng();
        
        this.getAddress(position.lat, position.lng);// This line is added
       // this.coor=e.latitude+" "+e.longitude;
        console.log(this.coor);
       
      });
    });
  }
  
  //The function below is added
  getAddress(lat: number, long: number) {
    let options: NativeGeocoderOptions = {
      useLocale: true,
      maxResults: 5
    };
    this.geocoder.reverseGeocode(lat, long, options).then(results => {
      this.address = Object.values(results[0]).reverse();
      console.log(this.address);
      
    });
  }
// The function below is added
  confirmPickupLocation() {
    let navigationextras: NavigationExtras = {
      state: {
        pickupLocation: this.address
       
        
      }
    };
    this.modalController.dismiss(this.coor);
  } ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Existe un plugin para verificar permisos en android llamado **Android Permissions**. que pudieras probar antes de pedir ubicación, llamandolo de esta forma:

```
this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION).then(
   result => {
          // Realiza aqui tu busqueda de ubicación
   }
);
```

Para más información puedes visitar la pagina oficial [Aqui](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions/)